# Use Google Drive API to view files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am currently working on a project wherein one of the requirements is to view a users Google Drive files on an iOS device. The SDK is all setup with oAuth 2.0 authentication and appropriate scopes. I've already pulled Google Plus, Calendar, and Drive data, but viewing the actual Drive files is proving to be harder than expected.

Currently i've got a table view with a list of all your Google Drive files, the idea is that when you click on them it should load the file.

Right now i've got a "DriveFileViewController", in it i've written:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.requestURL]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

The `self.requestURL` in that case is the `defaultOpenWithLink` that Google lists in their API explorer at http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.get.

The problem then is that the webView loads the requested URL but Google is asking for users to sign in again in the webView rather than showing them the file.

On my Mac, on the browser if you're authenticated and you click on the link from the API explorer it will work fine.

Im assuming their is some kind of cookie or header field that I need to set in my URL Request to let Google know the user is authenticated already and that they should be able to view their file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the example code to create a table view with a list of files,please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the access token as an Authorization header when loading an `embedLink` into a `WebView`.

```
 Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

It will authorize the document with the same user authorized and authenticated on the app.

Comment: I tried setting the Authorization header but it still presents the login form for me.  Any idea why?

Comment: I would also like to know how is this supposed to work